# What needs to be escaped in an onclick event taking a string?

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, escaping

I'm not sure what characters need to be escaped in my string. My PHP code is giving the string parameter, but sometimes it has quotes and double quotes that I'm not sure what to do with.

```
onclick="eventBox('This is the string ' // " "')"
```

Comment: Did you try searching on Google? http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/, http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quotes (`"`) should be replaced with `&quot;`. And backslash (`\`) prepended to `'`.

```
onclick="eventBox('This is the string \' // &quot; &quot;')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape the quotes or encode them so it parses correctly.

```
onclick="eventBox('This is the string \' // &quot; &quot;')"
```

Otherwise there will be a parse error because of mis-matching quotes

Comment: That won't work, it's a part of html and the first quote terminates the attribute value.

Comment: ;-) Almost. Except for, to make it correct you need to `;`-terminate entities ;-)

Comment: You know what, no need for duplicate answers. I'm deleting mine and up-ing yours...how do you like dem apples?

Comment: :)) I wasn't going to sue you for plagiarism ;-)

Comment: I only took your `&quot;`, i wouldn't call that plagiarism since i did originally state that they needed to be encoded. I just foolishly escaped them all in my example.

Comment: I wouldn't call that either. Besides, I do not hold copyright for `&quot;`. Also, It is probably a *quotation*, not plagiarism :)

Comment: Seriously, though, the flaw is that you overlooked two layers of escaping — one for xml/html and one for javascript. And this comment (let me modestly add) is a good reason to keep you answer around ;-)